# Wide space between picture and caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, plot, tikzscale

For some reason my v-space does not show up correctly! Does somebody know wy?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\resizebox{.5\linewidth}{!}{\input{Figures/NIRS/Extinction}}
\caption{Characteristic extinction coefficients of $O_2Hb$ and HHb in the Near Infrared range of the electromagnetic spectrum. This makes it possible to distinguish between these two compounds~\cite{Artinis}}
\label{fig:extinc}
\end{figure}\\
```

[image: Problem]

p.s. this problem also is present without resizebox (I also tried changing the tex width and height but then the caption is still way to big)

p.p.s. Other pictures show up normal!

Extinction.tex:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.5.0 running on MATLAB 8.1.
%Copyright (c) 2008--2014, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
%All rights reserved.
%Minimal pgfplots version: 1.3
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=3.36in,
height=2.58in,
at={(0in,0in)},
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=650,
axis x discontinuity=crunch,
xmax=1000,
xlabel={Wavelength [\textit{nm}]},
xmajorgrids,
ymode=log,
ymin=0,
ymax=3500,
yminorticks=true,
ylabel={$\text{Molar extinction coefficient [cm}^{\text{-1}}\text{(moles/l)}^{\text{-1}}\text{]}$},
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,fill=white,draw=black}
]
\addplot [color=black,solid,line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
650 3750\\
655 3481.5\\
660 3227\\
665 3011\\
670 2795\\
675 2591\\
680 2408\\
685 2224.5\\
690 2052\\
695 1923.5\\
700 1794\\
705 1661\\
710 1540\\
715 1432.5\\
720 1326\\
725 1224\\
730 1102\\
735 1102\\
740 1116\\
745 1236.5\\
750 1405\\
755 1551\\
760 1549\\
765 1435.5\\
770 1312\\
775 1188.5\\
780 1075\\
785 977.04\\
790 890.79\\
795 815.89\\
800 761.7\\
805 733.7\\
810 717.1\\
815 703.95\\
820 693.79\\
825 693.39\\
830 693\\
835 692.7\\
840 692.39\\
845 691.89\\
850 691.29\\
855 690.75\\
860 694.29\\
865 698.95\\
870 705.79\\
875 716.15\\
880 726.39\\
885 734.9\\
890 743.6\\
895 752.7\\
900 761.79\\
905 768.59\\
910 774.6\\
915 778.2\\
920 777.39\\
925 774.5\\
930 763.79\\
935 730.25\\
940 693.39\\
945 650.79\\
950 602.2\\
955 561.7\\
960 525.6\\
965 484.35\\
970 429.3\\
975 395.8\\
980 359.69\\
985 321.45\\
990 283.19\\
995 245.05\\
1000    206.8\\
};
\addlegendentry{HHb};
\addplot [color=gray,dashed,line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
650 368\\
655 340.3\\
660 319.6\\
665 305.6\\
670 294\\
675 283.8\\
680 277.6\\
685 273.6\\
690 276\\
695 280.6\\
700 290\\
705 300.4\\
710 314\\
715 328.6\\
720 348\\
725 368.2\\
730 390\\
735 413.2\\
740 446\\
745 480.4\\
750 518\\
755 555.2\\
760 586\\
765 616.4\\
770 650\\
775 683.2\\
780 710\\
785 735.4\\
790 756\\
795 779.2\\
800 816\\
805 840\\
810 864\\
815 883.6\\
820 916\\
825 950.6\\
830 974\\
835 996.3\\
840 1022\\
845 1046.5\\
850 1058\\
855 1069.5\\
860 1092\\
865 1114.5\\
870 1128\\
875 1140.5\\
880 1154\\
885 1167.5\\
890 1178\\
895 1188\\
900 1198\\
905 1207.5\\
910 1214\\
915 1220\\
920 1224\\
925 1227\\
930 1222\\
935 1216.5\\
940 1214\\
945 1211\\
950 1204\\
955 1196\\
960 1186\\
965 1175.5\\
970 1162\\
975 1147.5\\
980 1128\\
985 1107\\
990 1080\\
995 1052\\

1000    1024\\
};
\addlegendentry{$O_2Hb$};
\pgfkeys{%
    /pgf/number format/set thousands separator = {}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without knowing, what `Figures/NIRS/Extinction.tex` contains, it is difficult to say.

Comment: Sorry! Ofcourse!

Comment: the `\\ ` after `\end{figure}` is always wrong, that should be deleted, other than that I can not see any use of `\vspace` in your fragments. It always help if you post a _complete_ document that shows the problem.

Comment: Without the \\, the problem still exists (tried several things to keep the caption right under the figure). I assumed it was a "\vspace" problem while the vertical space between the figure and caption is wrong.

Comment: If I add `\fbox{...}` around the `\resizebox...` I see that the picture has a wide space below it.

Comment: Hmm, I see, changing the height in the texfile does not give the satisfactory result (makes everything smaller). I wonder why that wide space is below the figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture has very large white space below the diagram. I couldn't find what's causing it, but a workaround is to trim it using the `gincltex` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgfplots,gincltex}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[trim=0 6cm 0 0,width=.5\linewidth]{martinpicture.tex} 

\caption{Characteristic extinction coefficients of O$_2$Hb and HHb in the Near Infrared range of the
electromagnetic spectrum. This makes it possible to distinguish between these two
compounds~\cite{Artinis}}\label{fig:extinc}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The 6cm has been computed by eye.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks that indirectly solved my problem!

Answer (score 3):

The extra space at the bottom of the image is caused by option `separate axis lines`. Probably a bug in `pgfplots`. I do not see, that this option is really needed.

Other issues:

- Units can be set via package `siunitx`, see the following example.
- The invisible inner margin of option `inner sep` contributes to the bounding box. It can be removed by using `outer sep` instead:

  ```
  /tikz/inner sep to outer sep/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=.3333em},
  x tick label style=inner sep to outer sep,
  x label style=inner sep to outer sep,
  y label style=inner sep to outer sep,
  ```
- The following example sets the chemical abbreviations as chemical formulas of package `mhchem`.
- The placement of the discontinuity symbol is wrong, there is no discontinuity between 650 and 700. For example, this can be fixed by
  `xmin=620` instead of `xmin=650`. Also the y axis needs the same treatment
  (e.g. `xmin=101`). IMHO, it looks quite odd and wastes space, thus the following example removes the discontinuities.
- When the plot is scaled using `\resizebox` this also affects labels and line widths. This can be avoided by using package `tikzscale`. The plot is put in a file `Extinction.tikz` with file name extension `.tikz` and included via `\includegraphics[...]{Extinction.tikz}`. The width can then be specified directly via option `width=.5\linewidth`. The height can indirectly be set by option `axisratio`. The example uses the font size `\footnotesize` (`\small` would be more readable).
- The description for the y axis is quite long, thus the example manually moves the description a little to the bottom to save vertical space (see `\kern`).

Full example, first `Extinction.tikz`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  % separate axis lines,
  % outer axis line style={very thin,black},
  xmin=650, % or 620, if the discontinuity symbol is used
  % axis x discontinuity=crunch,
  % axis y discontinuity=crunch,
  xmax=1000,
  xlabel={Wavelength [\si{\nano\metre}]},
  xmajorgrids,
  ymode=log,
  ymin=100, % or 101, if the discontinuity symbol is used
  ymax=3500,
  ytickten={2, 2.5, 3, 3.5},
  yminorticks=true,
  ylabel={%
    \kern-1.5em
    Molar extinction coefficient %
    % [\si{\centi\metre^{-1}(\mole/\litre)^{-1}}]%
    [\si{\per\centi\metre\per\mole\litre}]%
  },
  ymajorgrids,
  yminorgrids,
  legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,fill=white,draw=black},
  /tikz/inner sep to outer sep/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=.3333em},
  x tick label style=inner sep to outer sep,
  x label style=inner sep to outer sep,
  y label style=inner sep to outer sep,
  node font=\footnotesize,
]
\addplot [color=black,solid,line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
650 3750\\
655 3481.5\\
660 3227\\
665 3011\\
670 2795\\
675 2591\\
680 2408\\
685 2224.5\\
690 2052\\
695 1923.5\\
700 1794\\
705 1661\\
710 1540\\
715 1432.5\\
720 1326\\
725 1224\\
730 1102\\
735 1102\\
740 1116\\
745 1236.5\\
750 1405\\
755 1551\\
760 1549\\
765 1435.5\\
770 1312\\
775 1188.5\\
780 1075\\
785 977.04\\
790 890.79\\
795 815.89\\
800 761.7\\
805 733.7\\
810 717.1\\
815 703.95\\
820 693.79\\
825 693.39\\
830 693\\
835 692.7\\
840 692.39\\
845 691.89\\
850 691.29\\
855 690.75\\
860 694.29\\
865 698.95\\
870 705.79\\
875 716.15\\
880 726.39\\
885 734.9\\
890 743.6\\
895 752.7\\
900 761.79\\
905 768.59\\
910 774.6\\
915 778.2\\
920 777.39\\
925 774.5\\
930 763.79\\
935 730.25\\
940 693.39\\
945 650.79\\
950 602.2\\
955 561.7\\
960 525.6\\
965 484.35\\
970 429.3\\
975 395.8\\
980 359.69\\
985 321.45\\
990 283.19\\
995 245.05\\
1000    206.8\\
};
\addlegendentry{\ce{HHb}};
\addplot [color=gray,dashed,line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
650 368\\
655 340.3\\
660 319.6\\
665 305.6\\
670 294\\
675 283.8\\
680 277.6\\
685 273.6\\
690 276\\
695 280.6\\
700 290\\
705 300.4\\
710 314\\
715 328.6\\
720 348\\
725 368.2\\
730 390\\
735 413.2\\
740 446\\
745 480.4\\
750 518\\
755 555.2\\
760 586\\
765 616.4\\
770 650\\
775 683.2\\
780 710\\
785 735.4\\
790 756\\
795 779.2\\
800 816\\
805 840\\
810 864\\
815 883.6\\
820 916\\
825 950.6\\
830 974\\
835 996.3\\
840 1022\\
845 1046.5\\
850 1058\\
855 1069.5\\
860 1092\\
865 1114.5\\
870 1128\\
875 1140.5\\
880 1154\\
885 1167.5\\
890 1178\\
895 1188\\
900 1198\\
905 1207.5\\
910 1214\\
915 1220\\
920 1224\\
925 1227\\
930 1222\\
935 1216.5\\
940 1214\\
945 1211\\
950 1204\\
955 1196\\
960 1186\\
965 1175.5\\
970 1162\\
975 1147.5\\
980 1128\\
985 1107\\
990 1080\\
995 1052\\
1000    1024\\
};
\addlegendentry{\ce{O2Hb}};
\pgfkeys{%
    /pgf/number format/set thousands separator = {}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

And the main TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, pgfplots, graphicx, siunitx, tikzscale}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

% \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
% \setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
% \fbox{%
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, axisratio=1]{Extinction.tikz}%
}%

\caption{Characteristic extinction coefficients of \ce{O2Hb} and \ce{HHb} in the
Near Infrared range of the
electromagnetic spectrum. This makes it possible to distinguish between
these two
compounds~\cite{Artinis}}\label{fig:extinc}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With `\fbox` to show the bounding box of the plot:

> [image: Result with \fbox]