# TikZ datavisualization: pins / labels add whitespace between figure and caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, diagrams, tikz-datavisualization

I'm using TikZ's data visualization feature to create a figure. This is working fine, up to the point where I add pins and/or labels to the figure; doing so creates a large amount of whitespace between the figure proper and its caption. The following is an MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering%
        \caption{Pareto frontier of risky investments}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
            \datavisualization [
                scientific axes = clean
            ]
            [
                visualize as line/.list = { pareto, tangent },
                visualize as scatter/.list = { investments, portfolios },
                y axis = { 
                    label     = { $\mu$ [\%] },
                    attribute = M,
                    min value = 0,
                    max value = 25
                },
                x axis = { 
                    label     = { $\sigma$ [\%]}, 
                    attribute = S,
                    min value = 0,
                    max value = 70
                },
                pareto = {
                    label in data = {
                        when = S is 19,
                        text = Natasha Fund
                    },
                    label in data = {
                        when = S is 60,
                        text = Hannah Corporation
                    }
                },
                tangent = {
                    style = dashed,
                },
                investments  = {
                    pin in data = {
                        when = S is 0,
                        text = risk-free investment
                    }
                },
                portfolios = {
                    pin in data = {
                        when = S is 18.29379,
                        text' = $P^\star$
                    },
                }
            ]
            data [set = pareto, format = function] {
                var  t : interval [0:1] samples 1000;
                func M = 15 + 5*\value{t};
                func S = sqrt(3961*\value{t}^2 - 722*\value{t} + 361);
            }
            data [set = tangent, headline = {S, M}] {
                0, 3.2
                32.09828, 25
            }
            data [set = investments, headline = {S, M}] {
                0, 3.2
                19, 15
                60, 20
            }
            data [set = portfolios, headline = {S, M}] {
                18.29379, 15.62466
            }
            ;
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: MWE: extra whitespace in the presence of pins / labels in data]

Commenting out the pins / labels gives the intended result:

[image: MWE: no extra whitespace once pins / labels in data are removed]

Looking for similar questions, I found [Wide space between picture and caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251917/wide-space-between-picture-and-caption), but no solution. I'm stuck, and would appreciate any help, tips, pointers, or suggestions. Thanks!

*Addendum*: in case it might be relevant, I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows. I've updated MiKTex to make sure the issue's not caused by outdated packages, to no avail.

Comment: Losing the [scale=2.5] fixes the white space, but then the lables are way too big.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, that's an interesting observation. [scale=1.5] looks reasonable, both in terms of label placement and whitespace, so I might just run with that. Would still be nice to get to the bottom of this, however.

Comment: It is probably a bug.  Most people use pgfplots.  Also, \scalebox and \resizebox do not change the relative sizes of text and picture.

Comment: Another problem:  if you place the tikzpicture inside another box, it generates an odd error about trying to parse `3.2 32.09828` .as  a floating point number (when they are actually two numbers on different lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd suggest using the scaling features of the `datavisualization` library, rather than using `scale` directly. That is, add for example

```
x axis={length=12cm},
y axis={length=7cm}
```

to the `\datavisualization` options, to set the size of the axis. I did have to modify the pins a bit though, see comments in the code.

There are other methods as well:

- `scientific axes = {clean,width=12cm,height=7cm}` (`width` and `height` are attributes of `scientific axis`).
- `x axis={unit length=1cm per 10 units}` and similar for y axis. I.e. set the length that should be used by a given number of unit lengths.
- Might be others. I don't really know the library that well, scrolling through the manual might lead to more options.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
       \centering%
        \caption{Pareto frontier of risky investments}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=2.5]
            \datavisualization [
                scientific axes = clean,
                x axis={length=12cm},
                y axis={length=7cm}
            ]
            [
                visualize as line/.list = { pareto, tangent },
                visualize as scatter/.list = { investments, portfolios },
                y axis = { 
                    label     = { $\mu$ [\%] },
                    attribute = M,
                    min value = 0,
                    max value = 25
                },
                x axis = { 
                    label     = { $\sigma$ [\%]}, 
                    attribute = S,
                    min value = 0,
                    max value = 70
                },
                pareto = {
                    label in data = {
                        when = S is 19,
                        text' = Natasha Fund % changed from text to text'
                    },
                    label in data = {
                        when = S is 60,
                        text = Hannah Corporation
                    }
                },
                tangent = {
                    style = dashed,
                },
                investments  = {
                    pin in data = {
                        when = S is 0,
                        text = risk-free investment,
                        node style={right} % added
                    }
                },
                portfolios = {
                    pin in data = {
                        when = S is 18.29379,
                        text' = $P^\star$,
                        pin length = 1cm, % added
                        pin angle = -30 % added
                    },
                }
            ]
            data [set = pareto, format = function] {
                var  t : interval [0:1] samples 1000;
                func M = 15 + 5*\value{t};
                func S = sqrt(3961*\value{t}^2 - 722*\value{t} + 361);
            }
            data [set = tangent, headline = {S, M}] {
                0, 3.2
                32.09828, 25
            }
            data [set = investments, headline = {S, M}] {
                0, 3.2
                19, 15
                60, 20
            }
            data [set = portfolios, headline = {S, M}] {
                18.29379, 15.62466
            }
            ;
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```